Reporting Stage Statuses to GitHub for Pipeline Triggered by another Pipeline
I'm currently in the process of splitting our mono-pipeline into separate build, test, and deploy pipelines in Azure DevOps. Here’s how I’ve set up the triggers and resources:
In the build pipeline, I have:
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'

In the test pipeline, the setup is:
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: build
      source: foobar.build
      trigger:
        stages:
          - Publish
        tags:
          - build-success

This setup correctly triggers the test pipeline after the build pipeline completes the Publish stage and is tagged with build-success. It works as expected for pull requests as well as for branch builds like those on the master branch.
However, I'm facing an issue where the statuses of the different stages in the test pipeline are not being reported back to GitHub, but this problem only occurs for pull requests. The status reporting works correctly for branch builds on the master branch.
I need to ensure that GitHub accurately reflects the status (success/failure) of each stage in the test pipeline when triggered by a pull request. Is there a way to configure Azure DevOps to report these stage statuses back to GitHub for pull requests? If direct reporting isn't possible, what alternatives should I consider to achieve this functionality?

Based on your description, I created to pipelines foobar.build and foobar.test referencing the YAML definitions below from the master branch of my GitHub repo.
build.yml
trigger:
- master
# Use code from intermediate branch of PRId
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Publish
  jobs:
  - job: PublishJob
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]build-success"
      displayName: Add build tag

test.yml
trigger: none
pr: none # Prevent PR from triggering foobar.test pipeline

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: build
      source: foobar.build
      trigger:
        stages:
          - Publish
        tags:
          - build-success

steps:
- script: echo This is the downstream test pipeline
  displayName: Run downstream test pipeline


I could reproduce the issue, while it seemed the behavior was not related to the trigger reason but the source code that the pipeline consumed.
Per the Check status functionality for the branch, it only checks the pipeline status that uses the code from this branch as resource. We could see the foobar.test pipeline was not monitored by the Check status until the foobar.test pipeline was triggered.

However, when the build pipeline was triggered by a pull request, it would use the code from the intermediate branch of PRId rather than the code from target branch (master). Therefore, the source branch (dev) instead of the target branch of this PR would check the status of this pipeline run and only the run triggered by the PR.


In addition, after the PR was merged to master branch, it would trigger the build pipeline with Individual CI, which would process to trigger test pipeline with pipeline completion. Therefore, the runs of the build and test pipeline were visible for status check of master branch after merge.

Yes, is this considered a bug then?

Hi @Martijn, I think this is by-design rather than a bug, since the test pipeline during the PR workflow was neither using the code from source branch nor triggered by the PR validation (no pr defined in the test pipeline and it shouldn't be defined as the test pipeline was using pipeline completion trigger). Therefore, it was the expected behavior that the test pipeline run status in the PR workflow was not checked by the master or dev branch in my sample

In another word, if a pipeline run was neither using the code from a branch as resource nor triggered by PR validation (pr), its status should not be checked by this branch.

Since the merge commit of the PR will pushed to the master branch, which will trigger build pipeline by CI trigger, whose completion will proceed to trigger test pipeline. Hence, after PR merges, the master branch will check the status of both the runs of build and test pipelines as expected. May I know you would expect which branch to monitor the status of build and test pipelines during PR workflow, master or dev?

What would be the recommended course of action for my use-case? The reason we decided to split the mono-pipeline into dedicated build, test, deploy pipelines was two fold. 1) Having the ability to deploy whenever necessary, not coupled to a specific commit. 2) Deploy when tests fail for commits to master. Is it possible to configure the triggered pipeline like it was triggered by a PR? Or maybe create a task that triggers the test pipeline when the build pipeline is done and the Build.Reason is Pull Request?

Hi Martijn, Thanks for your sharing. Taking my sample PR (dev to master) workflow from build to test, the status of build pipeline run was checked by the PR source branch (dev); it was because it contained the pr trigger in its YAML definition and thus, the Build.Reason for the runs triggered this way was PullRequest.

However per your test pipeline, it didn't and shouldn't contain pr trigger (pr: none), since it should only be triggered by the build pipeline completion, right? Hence, during a PR workflow, the status of the downstream test pipeline run was unable to be checked by the PR source branch (dev).

In conclusion, it was impossible to have the status of test pipeline run reflected on the PR source branch during a PR workflow, if the test pipeline didn't define pr trigger (pr: none).

May I ask again if your expectation is to have the PR source branch (dev in my case) monitor the status of both build and test pipeline runs during a PR workflow? And would you accept manual control during the PR workflow? If yes, we can discuss a workaround to add pr trigger to your test pipeline and manually control the test pipeline to wait for the completion of build pipeline triggered by pr so as to make sure the test pipeline can consume the latest artifacts published by build pipeline.
